# C++ Getline issues (No instance of overloaded function "getline"

Tags: c++, visual-c++, getline

**I know I know.**
This question has been asked before, but I've looked at all the answers and none seem to solve my problem. When I use the getline function to get the contents of a line in the file, it doesn't work.

```
getline(file, line);
```

'File' is declared here:

```
ifstream File;
File.open("fruit.txt");
```

and 'line' is declared here:

```
int line = 0;
```

Getline is underlined in red with this message:

```
getline
no instance of overloaded function "getline" matches the argument list
argument types are :(std::ifstream, int)
```

What this means is no instance of getline has the argument list of the file stream and an integer.

This makes no sense as all the other questions on this matter state exactly that, that the arguments ***are*** the file stream and an integer.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

Here is the full code:

```
ifstream fruitFile;
fruitFile.open("fruit.txt");
int line = 0;
int C_FRUIT = getline(fruitFile, line);
fruitFile.close();
```

The first line should be a number, and I need it.

Comment: Please quote your sources.

Comment: Please give us enough code to replicate the problem. Also, can you explain what you are expecting this code to do? Honestly, I can't imagine what you think this will do.

Comment: You are confusing `std::getline` and `std::ifstream::getline`. Also, I'm pretty sure the latter does not do what you think it does. Look up their definition in [some docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/) to learn how both functions work in detail. (Also, don't use `std::ifstream::getline`.)

Comment: What should I use instead Baum mit Augen?

Comment: I still have no idea what you think that code does. Where do you think the line goes? Do you know what `getline` does? (Hint: It gets a line.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`getline()` will read one line of text.  It can't read directly an int.  This is why you get your error message.

You have to be aware that there are two `getline()`.  There is one which is `istream::getline()` and  `std::getline()`.  Both have different signatures.  The first is a member function of a stream and is defined in the stream header; the latter is defined in the `<string>` header.

But pay attention: the return value of `std::getline()` is not an `int` !  It's a stream reference.  This is why  you get a second compiler error.

Finally if you want to read an integer x,  it's easier to use extractors:

```
int value; 
fruitFile >> value; 
fruitFile.ignore(SIZE_MAX, '\n');   // in case you'd need to go to next line
```

Or if you really want to read an int in a full line:

```
string line;
getline(fruitFile, line); 
stringstream sst(line);     // creates a string stream: a stream that takes line as input
sst >> value;
```

Comment: Aha! Thank you this is perfect, people were not explaining fully enough for my to fix and understand my problem. <3

Answer (score 4):

The second argument of getline needs to be a string: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/

I think what you try to achieve is:

```
ifstream fruitFile;
fruitFile.open("fruit.txt");
int line = 0;
fruitFile >> line
fruitFile.close();
```

Comment: @owenbradstreet What does "This doesn't work" mean? Are you including `std::string`?

Comment: I'm using namespace std, and the second argument is a string. It still gives an error

Comment: @owenbradstreet -_- Please just post your compile error, and `using namespace std;` and `#include <string>` are not the same thing.

Comment: `std::basic_istream<char, std::chartraits<char>> &std::getline<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > (std :: basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> > &_lstr, std::string &_Str) +4 overloads no suitable conversion function from "std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> > " to "int" exits`

Comment: This answer does not bother explaining how or why this could help OP. OP's unwillingness to read documentation isn't helping either.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error. add this to your code to solve the problem

1. Add the `string` library

```cpp
include <string>
```

2. Add the below function call, where `string_variable` should be of type `string`.

```cpp
std::getline(cin, sting_variable)
```